Properly align video player in sceneview arcore
I'm using Sceneview's ExoPlayerNode to play a video when an augmented image is detected. This is working fine but the position of the video is way off. It's as if you were watching TV but situated above the TV looking down on the top of the TV and not sitting in front of the screen. I have tried position and direction of the Plane object but to no avail. Any suggestions?
in exoplayernode file
center: Position = Plane.DEFAULT_CENTER,
normal: Direction = Plane.DEFAULT_NORMAL,
...
in plane file
val DEFAULT_CENTER = Position(0.0f)
val DEFAULT_NORMAL = Direction(y = 1.0f) 

